# How to add values with a comma?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to insert values like this: 'aaaa, bbbb' in the database.

I am using this query:

```
INSERT INTO a (title) VALUES ('aaaa, bbbb');
```

but in the database is saved only aaaa.
Why ?

This is the script:

```
   $a = 'aaaa, bbbb';
   $query = "INSERT INTO test (title) VALUES ('".$a."');";
   $res = mysqli_query($db_con, $query) or die("fail: " . $query . ' Error:' . mysqli_error());
```

Comment: What type is your `title` field?

Comment: What is your title field type and length?

Comment: title is varchar(100)

Comment: How are you doing the insertion? Via PHP?

Comment: You have `sql-injection` for `$a`, but for this data-case all should be ok.

Comment: If you execute via the DB interface does that full date write? Also is this a simplified version or your verbatim code?

Comment: Why are you really doing, storing CSV data, or a real title?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong in your SQL.

I make [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/736c22/1) to demonstrate that:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
 id int primary key auto_increment,
 title varchar(100) 
);

INSERT INTO t (title) VALUES('aaaaa, bbbbb'), ('ccccc, ddddd');
SELECT * FROM t;

id  title
1   aaaaa, bbbbb
2   ccccc, ddddd
```

Double-check you environment: how you fetch values, have you some related triggers etc.

---

Correct way to make queries like this, is using prepared statements:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO a (title) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $a);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or, procedural style:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO a (title) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_con, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($db_con, "s", $a);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me:

```
mysql> create table xrobot_test (
    -> title varchar(100)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe xrobot_test;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| title | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO xrobot_test (title) VALUES ('aaaa, bbbb');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from xrobot_test;
+------------+
| title      |
+------------+
| aaaa, bbbb |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```